# Probability of two line segments drawn through lattice points in a $[0,2024] \times [0,2024]$ grid intersecting within the grid

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Question: Four lattice points within the $[0,2024] \times [0,2024]$ coordinate grid are chosen uniformly at random. Compute the probability that any two lines connected from pairwise points intersect within the grid.

---

For this question, I thought it was a good idea to split into cases:

1. All four points lie on the same line
2. Three points lie on the same line, but the fourth point does not lie on that line
3. No three points lie on the same line

However, I am unsure how to proceed with any of these cases. I will edit this post if I make any progress.

Comment: I mean this is brute forceable with code if you really just need the answer- but I take it you want something more than just the final probability?

Comment: @EvanSemet Yes, I would like some nice way to do this for 2024 (and preferably, for a general [0,n] x [0,n] grid)